# Multiple sql rows to a single row of data

Tags: sql, sql-server

i need an sql query to combine mutliple row select statements to single row.

Have a table [PriceHistory] to store daily metal prices as shown below based on date:

[existing db values example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCkP6.jpg)

Need a query to display the [PriceHistory].OpenPrice column of [PriceHistory].SpotMetal=gold as GoldSpot and [PriceHistory].SpotMetal=silver as SilverSpot in a single row when we input current system date using date() function and check it with [PriceHistory].SpotDate

desired output:

[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6NPH.jpg)

I wrote a query as below but it displays as separate rows :

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @date DATETIME
SET @date=CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
SELECT (CASE WHEN [OpenPrice] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE  [OpenPrice] END) AS GoldSpot FROM [][dbo].[PriceHistory] WHERE [SpotMetal]='Gold' and [SpotDate]=@date;
SELECT (CASE WHEN [OpenPrice] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE  [OpenPrice] END) AS SilverSpot FROM [][dbo].[PriceHistory] WHERE [SpotMetal]='Silver' and [SpotDate]=@date;
END
```

[Received output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfeaA.jpg)

Could u pls suggest a correction to my query so that i get desired output

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question and replace the mages with text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BEGIN 
DECLARE @date DATETIME 
SET @date = CAST('2015-01-01' AS DATE)
SELECT * FROM   
(
    SELECT SpotMetal
            ,OpenPrice
    FROM PriceHistory
    WHERE spotdate = @date
) t 
PIVOT(
    SUM(OpenPrice) 
    FOR SpotMetal IN (
        [Gold], 
        [Silver])
) AS pivot_table

END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `PIVOT`, it should work:

```
BEGIN 
DECLARE @date DATETIME 
SET @date = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) 
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[PriceHistory] WHERE [SpotDate] = @DATE) M
 PIVOT (SUM([OpenPrice] FOR [SpotMetal] IN ('Gold','Silver'))
 PIVOT TABLE;
END
```